# How to disable/enable MIUI optimization in Redmi devices

Tags: android, kotlin, miui, redmi-device

Our client requirement is they don't want to navigate the developer page and turn on the MIUI Optimization. How do I achieve to turn on MIUI Optimization Programmatically in Redmi note 10 pro. Is it possible then let me.

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm also very curious is there any API for that, but personally I doubt, sadly...